# Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -9 "+ PID ) not working

Tags: android, eclipse

i don't know why the Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -9"+PID) won't work, but with the adb.exe shell it works perfectly ...!

```
OnClickListener killButtonListner = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Process ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -9 " + PID);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Process killed" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
    killButton.setOnClickListener(killButtonListner);
}
```

Comment: Does the user running the app have a "License to kill" this process?

Comment: yes with this : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />

Comment: What a **BAD PRACTICE**! It's even **worse** than using `system.exit(0);` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292016/difference-between-finish-and-system-exit0

Comment: Please take a look at my code !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use:

[`Process.killProcess(int pid)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29)

to keep it as Android code, without shelling out? This will be more reliable.

Comment: I try it but it doesn't work!
well, in my application I get all the processes that have the PPID equals to ZYGOTE PID. i add them to a ListView wich allows me to click on the process i want to kill. Here is my code below